# Why do I get in gdb "Cannot access memory at address 0x..." while inspecting a core dump?

Tags: c++, memory-management, assembly, gdb, coredump

I get this message when I try to print the following line while analysing a core dump.

```
(gdb) p/x *($esi)
Cannot access memory at address 0xe6d3a030
```

I mention that the address pointed by `%esi` `(0xe6d3a030)` should point to some valid allocated data. ( when I run this program myself and break on the same instruction this print has some meaningful information )

What are the possible causes for this? Am I missing some info from the core dump?

If yes what information am I missing? Shouldn't the core dump contain a snapshot of all the allocated memory?

edit:
when I use in gdb "maintenance info sections" command while the coredump is loaded I get the info presented bellow. I can see that the address 0xe6d3a030 is in the range  `0xe6d00000->0xe6dfb000 at 0x0f5aa000: load93 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS` Doesn't this mean it was loaded?

```
(gdb) maintenance info sections 
Exec file:
    `/home/Administrator/Documents/coredump/myproc-debug-8.1.bin', file type elf32-i386.
    0x8048134->0x8048147 at 0x00000134: .interp ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x8048148->0x8048168 at 0x00000148: .note.ABI-tag ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x8048168->0x804818c at 0x00000168: .note.gnu.build-id ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x804818c->0x80acd94 at 0x0000018c: .gnu.hash ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x80acd94->0x8180d14 at 0x00064d94: .dynsym ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x8180d14->0x839a757 at 0x00138d14: .dynstr ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x839a758->0x83b4f48 at 0x00352758: .gnu.version ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x83b4f48->0x83b50c8 at 0x0036cf48: .gnu.version_r ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x83b50c8->0x83b5150 at 0x0036d0c8: .rel.dyn ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x83b5150->0x83b5950 at 0x0036d150: .rel.plt ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x83b5950->0x83b5980 at 0x0036d950: .init ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0x83b5980->0x83b6990 at 0x0036d980: .plt ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0x83b6990->0x8d9771c at 0x0036e990: .text ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0x8d9771c->0x8d97738 at 0x00d4f71c: .fini ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0x8d97740->0x904ef6a at 0x00d4f740: .rodata ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x904ef6c->0x9099588 at 0x01006f6c: .eh_frame_hdr ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x9099588->0x92015b4 at 0x01051588: .eh_frame ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x92015b4->0x923e63a at 0x011b95b4: .gcc_except_table ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x923f63c->0x923fbe8 at 0x011f663c: .ctors ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x923fbe8->0x923fbf0 at 0x011f6be8: .dtors ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x923fbf0->0x923fbf4 at 0x011f6bf0: .jcr ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x923fbf4->0x923fce4 at 0x011f6bf4: .dynamic ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x923fce4->0x923fce8 at 0x011f6ce4: .got ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x923fce8->0x92400f4 at 0x011f6ce8: .got.plt ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x9240100->0x929032c at 0x011f7100: .data ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x9290340->0x9302aa8 at 0x0124732c: .bss ALLOC
    0x0000->0x0087 at 0x0124732c: .comment READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x19810 at 0x012473b3: .debug_aranges READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x1b9b06 at 0x01260bc3: .debug_pubnames READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x1666e04 at 0x0141a6c9: .debug_info READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x18736b at 0x02a814cd: .debug_abbrev READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x2f1118 at 0x02c08838: .debug_line READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x1f9f4 at 0x02ef9950: .debug_frame READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x321836 at 0x02f19344: .debug_str READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x3b2f6e at 0x0323ab7a: .debug_loc READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x115b29 at 0x035edae8: .debug_pubtypes READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x48290 at 0x03703611: .debug_ranges READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
Core file:
    `/home/Administrator/Documents/coredump/core.myproc.20815', file type elf32-i386.
    0x0000->0x7eb4 at 0x000016f4: note0 READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00001750: .reg/21153 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00001750: .reg HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x00a0 at 0x0000183c: .auxv HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x000018f0: .reg2/21153 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x000018f0: .reg2 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00001970: .reg-xfp/21153 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00001970: .reg-xfp HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00001c10: .reg/21158 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00001c6c: .reg2/21158 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00001cec: .reg-xfp/21158 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00001f8c: .reg/20924 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00001fe8: .reg2/20924 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00002068: .reg-xfp/20924 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00002308: .reg/21205 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00002364: .reg2/21205 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x000023e4: .reg-xfp/21205 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00002684: .reg/21204 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x000026e0: .reg2/21204 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00002760: .reg-xfp/21204 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00002a00: .reg/21156 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00002a5c: .reg2/21156 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00002adc: .reg-xfp/21156 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00002d7c: .reg/21201 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00002dd8: .reg2/21201 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00002e58: .reg-xfp/21201 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x000030f8: .reg/21157 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00003154: .reg2/21157 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x000031d4: .reg-xfp/21157 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00003474: .reg/21150 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x000034d0: .reg2/21150 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00003550: .reg-xfp/21150 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x000037f0: .reg/21203 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x0000384c: .reg2/21203 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x000038cc: .reg-xfp/21203 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00003b6c: .reg/21200 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00003bc8: .reg2/21200 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00003c48: .reg-xfp/21200 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00003ee8: .reg/21154 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00003f44: .reg2/21154 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00003fc4: .reg-xfp/21154 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00004264: .reg/21202 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x000042c0: .reg2/21202 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00004340: .reg-xfp/21202 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x000045e0: .reg/20830 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x0000463c: .reg2/20830 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x000046bc: .reg-xfp/20830 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x0000495c: .reg/20917 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x000049b8: .reg2/20917 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00004a38: .reg-xfp/20917 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00004cd8: .reg/22600 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00004d34: .reg2/22600 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00004db4: .reg-xfp/22600 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00005054: .reg/20928 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x000050b0: .reg2/20928 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00005130: .reg-xfp/20928 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x000053d0: .reg/21258 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x0000542c: .reg2/21258 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x000054ac: .reg-xfp/21258 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x0000574c: .reg/20918 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x000057a8: .reg2/20918 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00005828: .reg-xfp/20918 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00005ac8: .reg/20915 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00005b24: .reg2/20915 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00005ba4: .reg-xfp/20915 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00005e44: .reg/20923 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00005ea0: .reg2/20923 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00005f20: .reg-xfp/20923 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x000061c0: .reg/21206 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x0000621c: .reg2/21206 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x0000629c: .reg-xfp/21206 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x0000653c: .reg/21160 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00006598: .reg2/21160 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00006618: .reg-xfp/21160 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x000068b8: .reg/21151 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00006914: .reg2/21151 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00006994: .reg-xfp/21151 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00006c34: .reg/22042 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00006c90: .reg2/22042 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00006d10: .reg-xfp/22042 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00006fb0: .reg/20929 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x0000700c: .reg2/20929 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x0000708c: .reg-xfp/20929 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x0000732c: .reg/20925 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00007388: .reg2/20925 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00007408: .reg-xfp/20925 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x000076a8: .reg/20919 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00007704: .reg2/20919 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00007784: .reg-xfp/20919 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00007a24: .reg/21159 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00007a80: .reg2/21159 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00007b00: .reg-xfp/21159 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00007da0: .reg/21155 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00007dfc: .reg2/21155 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00007e7c: .reg-xfp/21155 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x0000811c: .reg/20815 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00008178: .reg2/20815 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x000081f8: .reg-xfp/20815 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00008498: .reg/21165 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x000084f4: .reg2/21165 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00008574: .reg-xfp/21165 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00008814: .reg/20920 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00008870: .reg2/20920 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x000088f0: .reg-xfp/20920 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00008b90: .reg/20921 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00008bec: .reg2/20921 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00008c6c: .reg-xfp/20921 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00008f0c: .reg/21216 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00008f68: .reg2/21216 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00008fe8: .reg-xfp/21216 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00009288: .reg/21189 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x000092e4: .reg2/21189 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00009364: .reg-xfp/21189 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x742000->0x743000 at 0x0000a000: load1a ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0x743000->0x743000 at 0x0000b000: load1b ALLOC READONLY CODE
    0x760000->0x761000 at 0x0000b000: load2 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x761000->0x762000 at 0x0000c000: load3 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0x764000->0x765000 at 0x0000d000: load4a ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0x765000->0x765000 at 0x0000e000: load4b ALLOC READONLY CODE
    0x8ed000->0x8ed000 at 0x0000e000: load5 ALLOC READONLY
    0x8ee000->0x8f0000 at 0x0000e000: load6 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x8f0000->0x8f1000 at 0x00010000: load7 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0x8f1000->0x8f4000 at 0x00011000: load8 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0x8f6000->0x8f7000 at 0x00014000: load9a ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0x8f7000->0x8f7000 at 0x00015000: load9b ALLOC READONLY CODE
    0x90d000->0x90e000 at 0x00015000: load10 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x90e000->0x90f000 at 0x00016000: load11 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0x90f000->0x911000 at 0x00017000: load12 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0x913000->0x914000 at 0x00019000: load13a ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0x914000->0x914000 at 0x0001a000: load13b ALLOC READONLY CODE
    0x93b000->0x93c000 at 0x0001a000: load14 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x93c000->0x93d000 at 0x0001b000: load15 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0x93f000->0x940000 at 0x0001c000: load16a ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0x940000->0x940000 at 0x0001d000: load16b ALLOC READONLY CODE
    0xa20000->0xa24000 at 0x0001d000: load17 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xa24000->0xa26000 at 0x00021000: load18 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xa26000->0xa2c000 at 0x00023000: load19 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xa2e000->0xa2f000 at 0x00029000: load20a ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0xa2f000->0xa2f000 at 0x0002a000: load20b ALLOC READONLY CODE
    0xa4b000->0xa4c000 at 0x0002a000: load21 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xa4e000->0xa4f000 at 0x0002b000: load22a ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0xa4f000->0xa4f000 at 0x0002c000: load22b ALLOC READONLY CODE
    0xa55000->0xa56000 at 0x0002c000: load23 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xa56000->0xa57000 at 0x0002d000: load24 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xd68000->0xd69000 at 0x0002e000: load25 ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0x8048000->0x8049000 at 0x0002f000: load26a ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0x8049000->0x8049000 at 0x00030000: load26b ALLOC READONLY CODE
    0x923f000->0x9291000 at 0x00030000: load27 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0x9291000->0x9303000 at 0x00082000: load28 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0x9303000->0x9303000 at 0x000f4000: load29 ALLOC
    0xa5b6000->0x11091000 at 0x000f4000: load30 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xdcf00000->0xdcf4a000 at 0x06bcf000: load31 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xdcf4a000->0xdcf4a000 at 0x06c19000: load32 ALLOC READONLY
    0xdd100000->0xdd138000 at 0x06c19000: load33 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xdd138000->0xdd138000 at 0x06c51000: load34 ALLOC READONLY
    0xdd2f4000->0xdd2f5000 at 0x06c51000: load35 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xdd2f5000->0xddffe000 at 0x06c52000: load36 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xddffe000->0xddfff000 at 0x0795b000: load37 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xddfff000->0xde9ff000 at 0x0795c000: load38 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xde9ff000->0xdea00000 at 0x0835c000: load39 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xdea00000->0xdf400000 at 0x0835d000: load40 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xdf400000->0xdf462000 at 0x08d5d000: load41 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xdf462000->0xdf462000 at 0x08dbf000: load42 ALLOC READONLY
    0xdf500000->0xdf521000 at 0x08dbf000: load43 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xdf521000->0xdf521000 at 0x08de0000: load44 ALLOC READONLY
    0xdf600000->0xdf641000 at 0x08de0000: load45 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xdf641000->0xdf641000 at 0x08e21000: load46 ALLOC READONLY
    0xdf7ff000->0xdf800000 at 0x08e21000: load47 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xdf800000->0xe0200000 at 0x08e22000: load48 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe0200000->0xe0221000 at 0x09822000: load49 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe0221000->0xe0221000 at 0x09843000: load50 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe0300000->0xe0321000 at 0x09843000: load51 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe0321000->0xe0321000 at 0x09864000: load52 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe0400000->0xe0421000 at 0x09864000: load53 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe0421000->0xe0421000 at 0x09885000: load54 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe0500000->0xe0521000 at 0x09885000: load55 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe0521000->0xe0521000 at 0x098a6000: load56 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe0600000->0xe0621000 at 0x098a6000: load57 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe0621000->0xe0621000 at 0x098c7000: load58 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe0700000->0xe0742000 at 0x098c7000: load59 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe0742000->0xe0742000 at 0x09909000: load60 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe0800000->0xe0821000 at 0x09909000: load61 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe0821000->0xe0821000 at 0x0992a000: load62 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe09ff000->0xe0a00000 at 0x0992a000: load63 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe0a00000->0xe1400000 at 0x0992b000: load64 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe1400000->0xe1438000 at 0x0a32b000: load65 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe1438000->0xe1438000 at 0x0a363000: load66 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe15fc000->0xe15fd000 at 0x0a363000: load67 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe15fd000->0xe1ffd000 at 0x0a364000: load68 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe1ffd000->0xe1ffe000 at 0x0ad64000: load69 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe1ffe000->0xe29fe000 at 0x0ad65000: load70 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe29fe000->0xe29ff000 at 0x0b765000: load71 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe29ff000->0xe33ff000 at 0x0b766000: load72 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe33ff000->0xe3400000 at 0x0c166000: load73 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe3400000->0xe3e00000 at 0x0c167000: load74 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe3e00000->0xe3ebc000 at 0x0cb67000: load75 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe3ebc000->0xe3ebc000 at 0x0cc23000: load76 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe3ffd000->0xe3ffe000 at 0x0cc23000: load77 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe3ffe000->0xe49fe000 at 0x0cc24000: load78 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe49fe000->0xe49ff000 at 0x0d624000: load79 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe49ff000->0xe53ff000 at 0x0d625000: load80 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe53ff000->0xe5400000 at 0x0e025000: load81 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe5400000->0xe5e00000 at 0x0e026000: load82 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe5e00000->0xe5efd000 at 0x0ea26000: load83 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe5efd000->0xe5efd000 at 0x0eb23000: load84 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe5f00000->0xe5f21000 at 0x0eb23000: load85 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe5f21000->0xe5f21000 at 0x0eb44000: load86 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe6000000->0xe6044000 at 0x0eb44000: load87 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe6044000->0xe6044000 at 0x0eb88000: load88 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe61ff000->0xe6200000 at 0x0eb88000: load89 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe6200000->0xe6c00000 at 0x0eb89000: load90 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe6c00000->0xe6c21000 at 0x0f589000: load91 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe6c21000->0xe6c21000 at 0x0f5aa000: load92 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe6d00000->0xe6dfb000 at 0x0f5aa000: load93 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe6dfb000->0xe6dfb000 at 0x0f6a5000: load94 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe6e00000->0xe6e21000 at 0x0f6a5000: load95 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe6e21000->0xe6e21000 at 0x0f6c6000: load96 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe6f00000->0xe6f21000 at 0x0f6c6000: load97 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe6f21000->0xe6f21000 at 0x0f6e7000: load98 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe7000000->0xe7021000 at 0x0f6e7000: load99 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe7021000->0xe7021000 at 0x0f708000: load100 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe7100000->0xe7137000 at 0x0f708000: load101 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe7137000->0xe7137000 at 0x0f73f000: load102 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe7200000->0xe7221000 at 0x0f73f000: load103 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe7221000->0xe7221000 at 0x0f760000: load104 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe7300000->0xe7321000 at 0x0f760000: load105 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe7321000->0xe7321000 at 0x0f781000: load106 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe7400000->0xe7421000 at 0x0f781000: load107 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe7421000->0xe7421000 at 0x0f7a2000: load108 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe75ff000->0xe7600000 at 0x0f7a2000: load109 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe7600000->0xe8000000 at 0x0f7a3000: load110 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe8000000->0xe8100000 at 0x101a3000: load111 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe8100000->0xe8121000 at 0x102a3000: load112 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe8121000->0xe8121000 at 0x102c4000: load113 ALLOC READONLY
    0xe8200000->0xe8300000 at 0x102c4000: load114 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe83f6000->0xe83f7000 at 0x103c4000: load115 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe83f7000->0xe8df7000 at 0x103c5000: load116 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe8df7000->0xe8df8000 at 0x10dc5000: load117 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe8df8000->0xe97f8000 at 0x10dc6000: load118 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe97f8000->0xe97f9000 at 0x117c6000: load119 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe97f9000->0xea1f9000 at 0x117c7000: load120 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xea1f9000->0xea1fa000 at 0x121c7000: load121 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xea1fa000->0xeabfa000 at 0x121c8000: load122 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xeabfa000->0xeabfb000 at 0x12bc8000: load123 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xeabfb000->0xeb5fb000 at 0x12bc9000: load124 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xeb5fb000->0xeb5fc000 at 0x135c9000: load125 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xeb5fc000->0xebffc000 at 0x135ca000: load126 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xebffc000->0xebffd000 at 0x13fca000: load127 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xebffd000->0xec9fd000 at 0x13fcb000: load128 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xec9fd000->0xec9fe000 at 0x149cb000: load129 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xec9fe000->0xed3fe000 at 0x149cc000: load130 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xed3fe000->0xed3ff000 at 0x153cc000: load131 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xed3ff000->0xeddff000 at 0x153cd000: load132 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xeddff000->0xede00000 at 0x15dcd000: load133 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xede00000->0xee800000 at 0x15dce000: load134 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xee800000->0xeea00000 at 0x167ce000: load135 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xeea00000->0xeea2b000 at 0x169ce000: load136 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xeea2b000->0xeea2b000 at 0x169f9000: load137 ALLOC READONLY
    0xeeb00000->0xeeb2c000 at 0x169f9000: load138 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xeeb2c000->0xeeb2c000 at 0x16a25000: load139 ALLOC READONLY
    0xeec00000->0xeec21000 at 0x16a25000: load140 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xeec21000->0xeec21000 at 0x16a46000: load141 ALLOC READONLY
    0xeed64000->0xeedfb000 at 0x16a46000: load142 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xeedfb000->0xeedfc000 at 0x16add000: load143 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xeedfc000->0xef7fc000 at 0x16ade000: load144 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xef7fc000->0xef7fd000 at 0x174de000: load145 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xef7fd000->0xf01fd000 at 0x174df000: load146 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf01fd000->0xf01fe000 at 0x17edf000: load147 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf01fe000->0xf0bfe000 at 0x17ee0000: load148 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf0bfe000->0xf0bff000 at 0x188e0000: load149 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf0bff000->0xf15ff000 at 0x188e1000: load150 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf15ff000->0xf1600000 at 0x192e1000: load151 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf1600000->0xf2000000 at 0x192e2000: load152 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf2000000->0xf2100000 at 0x19ce2000: load153 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf2100000->0xf2121000 at 0x19de2000: load154 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf2121000->0xf2121000 at 0x19e03000: load155 ALLOC READONLY
    0xf2200000->0xf2221000 at 0x19e03000: load156 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf2221000->0xf2221000 at 0x19e24000: load157 ALLOC READONLY
    0xf234d000->0xf23fd000 at 0x19e24000: load158 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf23fd000->0xf23fe000 at 0x19ed4000: load159 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf23fe000->0xf2dfe000 at 0x19ed5000: load160 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf2dfe000->0xf2dff000 at 0x1a8d5000: load161 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf2dff000->0xf37ff000 at 0x1a8d6000: load162 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf37ff000->0xf3800000 at 0x1b2d6000: load163 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf3800000->0xf4200000 at 0x1b2d7000: load164 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf4200000->0xf4221000 at 0x1bcd7000: load165 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf4221000->0xf4221000 at 0x1bcf8000: load166 ALLOC READONLY
    0xf4349000->0xf43fd000 at 0x1bcf8000: load167 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf43fd000->0xf43fe000 at 0x1bdac000: load168 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf43fe000->0xf4dfe000 at 0x1bdad000: load169 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf4dfe000->0xf4dff000 at 0x1c7ad000: load170 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf4dff000->0xf57ff000 at 0x1c7ae000: load171 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf57ff000->0xf5800000 at 0x1d1ae000: load172 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf5800000->0xf6200000 at 0x1d1af000: load173 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf6200000->0xf6300000 at 0x1dbaf000: load174 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf6339000->0xf6366000 at 0x1dcaf000: load175 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf6366000->0xf6367000 at 0x1dcdc000: load176 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf6367000->0xf6d67000 at 0x1dcdd000: load177 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf6d67000->0xf6d68000 at 0x1e6dd000: load178 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf6d68000->0xf77ae000 at 0x1e6de000: load179 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf77b7000->0xf77bb000 at 0x1f124000: load180 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xfff0b000->0xfff21000 at 0x1f128000: load181 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
```

Comment: I'm not a core-dump guru, but I'd say if there is content for that area in your core file, it should stand at offset `0x0f5aa000` in the core file. Could that be some in-kernel buffers that have been somehow extracted (you seem to have a whole lot of them) or maybe you're running your 32-bit executable on a 64-bit system, which could therefore allow it to use full 4GB of virtual adresses rather than the usual 3GB.

Comment: @sylvainulg Yes, the 32bit excutable is ran on a 64 bit system and also I inspect the credump on a 64bit machine.

Comment: you are probably missing some libs.
1. in gdb get libs with `info sharedlibrary`
2. copy those libs to your host
3. do `set solib-absolute-prefix $pathToLibsRoot` in gdb before loading core file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

that looks like an in-kernel memory reference to me (above 0xc0000000, assuming Linux and 32-bit process). To find out, check out /proc/{yourpid}/maps

> Shouldn't the core dump contain a snapshot of all the allocated memory?

It should, but if something has corrupted your process' memory, you've got a snapshot of corrupted program state, and thus some garbage may be found where valid pointers are expected.

> What are the possible causes for this? Am I missing some info from the core dump?

I note that when running a 32-bit executable on a 64-bit system, the full 4GB address space can be used by the process. e.g.

```
ia32kernel# pmap `pidof cat` 
004e8000    108K r-x--  /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
00503000      4K r----  /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
00504000      4K rw---  /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
006d3000   1380K r-x--  /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
0082c000      8K r----  /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
0082e000      4K rw---  /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
0082f000     12K rw---    [ anon ]
00f64000      4K r-x--    [ anon ]
08048000     48K r-x--  /bin/cat
08054000      4K r----  /bin/cat
08055000      4K rw---  /bin/cat
```

vs.

```
amd64kernel# pmap `pidof cat` 
0000000008048000     48K r-x--  /home/martin/cat
0000000008054000      4K r----  /home/martin/cat
0000000008055000      4K rw---  /home/martin/cat
0000000009e1d000    132K rw---    [ anon ]
00000000f766c000      4K rw---    [ anon ]
00000000f766d000   1280K r-x--  /lib32/libc-2.11.3.so
00000000f77ad000      4K -----  /lib32/libc-2.11.3.so
00000000f77ae000      8K r----  /lib32/libc-2.11.3.so
00000000f77b0000      4K rw---  /lib32/libc-2.11.3.so
00000000f77b1000     12K rw---    [ anon ]
00000000f77c0000      8K rw---    [ anon ]
00000000f77c2000      4K r-x--    [ anon ]
00000000f77c3000    112K r-x--  /lib32/ld-2.11.3.so
00000000f77df000      4K r----  /lib32/ld-2.11.3.so
00000000f77e0000      4K rw---  /lib32/ld-2.11.3.so
```

So if you're trying to inspect on a 32-bit machine a coredump that was captured on a 64-bit machine, those high-addresses libraries such as libc.so can't be mapped as expected even though the same 32-bit binary is used on both systems.